# Is there a way to create a shortcut to Proxy preferences in the Launcher?

Tags: 11.10, network-manager, proxy

In my university Campus I need to connect to Internet through a proxy. As I am  using a notebook, in Ubuntu 11.04 I set a shortcut in the Launcher to the proxy settings in order to "easily" change the proxy every time I go to the Campus. However, I can't figure out how to do this under Ubuntu 11.10.

Is there a way to create a shortcut pointing directly to proxy settings?

Even better, but less likely, is there a way to set the network settings so it changes the  proxy every time I connect to my Campus WiFi?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it doesn't automatically go to the tab for proxy settings, but it does bring you straight to the network settings: `gnome-control-center network`.

To create a launcher for it paste this into gedit:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Network Settings
Exec=gnome-control-center network
Icon=/usr/share/app-install/icons/gtk-network.png
Terminal=false
Categories=System;
StartupNotify=false
```

Save it somewhere as `network-settings.desktop`, and drag the file onto the Unity Launcher. Be sure to save the `network-settings.desktop` file somewhere it doesn't annoy you, because when you remove it it will disappear from the Unity Launcher as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can setup your gnome proxy configuration with the command line program **gssettings**

So you can create some bash scripts that will setup your proxy settings as needed

Use gsettings to see your gnome proxy configuration :

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.system.proxy
```

Example of setup script

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http port 8080
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host 'myproxy.domain.lan'
```

A second script that will disable the proxy

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'
```

See all available configurations keys there :

```
http://developer.gnome.org/ProxyConfiguration/
```